# Django: only blank page

Tags: python, django, apache, response, wsgi

I have a server with Apache and I would like to start website written in Django. I user mod_wsgi. Now I have it prepared. But the respond of a server is empty. And in error log, there is nothing. Do you know what is the reason why?

If some file could help (*.wsgi, settings.py) I will append it.

**Prochazky.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys
import site

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/prochazky/venv/.python-eggs'

site.addsitedir('/home/prochazky/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Prochazky.settings'

sys.path.append('/home/prochazky/')
sys.path.append('/home/prochazky/Prochazky/')

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Apache vhost:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/prochazky/Prochazky/Prochazky.wsgi
    ServerName testing.prochazky.net
    DocumentRoot /home/prochazky

    ErrorLog /home/prochazky/wsgi.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you show us your wsgi and apache vhost files?

Comment: BTW, using 'DocumentRoot /home/prochazky' is a really really bad idea. If you managed to remove WSGIScriptAlias, everything in the home directory of that account could end up being downloadable by people. Never point DocumentRoot at directories that contain stuff you don't want people ever to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying getting a hello world program working first and not Django. Watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

and read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

At a guess though, are you perhaps loading mod_python into the same Apache. An incompatible mod_python will cause exactly that symptom with merely a segmentation fault message in main Apache error log.

---

UPDATE 1

Are you loading mod_php into same Apache? It can sometimes have conflicting shared library requirements and will cause a crash. If you are also loading it, disable it from Apache configuration.

Also try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

This will force use of main interpreter which will avoid problems with third party extensions that aren't written properly to work in sub interpreters.

You really though need to look more closely at the main Apache error log, not the virtual host one. Run a 'tail -f' on it when you make a request and check for sure you are seeing messages there, specifically a segmentation fault or similar message. Such a message about process crashing and causing empty page will not show in virtual host error log.

Comment: Yes, I tried hello world program and it works. I don't have mod_python (yes, I am sure, I have already been looking for it).

Comment: Which was it though? PHP or possibly a third party C extension for Python?

Comment: @Graham Wow I've run mod_php and mod_wsgi together before and I didn't run into this problem... Now I'm scared to re-enable it on my server again. Are there any articles explaining this bug/issue? I'd love to read up on this just in case I need it.

Comment: @James It all comes down to library conflicts, or worst case symbol name conflicts. A couple of examples are http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#MySQL_Shared_Library_Conflicts and http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_MD5_Hash_Module_Conflict

Comment: @Graham That seems to be a pre-Python 2.5 issue? Which is probably why I haven't run into it. Thanks that is quite helpful.

Comment: @James Things are certainly better than they used to be. More common problem these days is people still loading really old mod_python at same time as mod_wsgi where mod_python statically linking Python instead of dynamically or mod_python trying to use a different Python version.

Comment: FWIW, the mod_python conflict issues are explained in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the template file your root url/view is empty or evaluates to empty?

For instance, if you have a template like so:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}blah blah{% endblock %}
```

and base.html doesn't use a block "content", then the content block from your template won't be used and your template will evaluate to empty despite having content.

Comment: The respond is totally empty - no headers, nothink. And I have this same application on my localhost and there it works. Unfortunatly it is different OS at all.

Comment: When I go there, it's giving me a 500 error so you might want to check the logs now. If you have your IP set as internal, it may be attempting to show you the error but failing that too, but won't show the error to me.

Comment: Yes, I see, I am working on it and trying somethink, for this reason there is e500.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my setup (names altered to protect the <strike>innocent</strike> guilty).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.domain.com 
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com 

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/site/django.wsgi

        <Directory /home/user/site/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None 
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
         ... etc etc etc.
```

I think you need the `<directory>` to allow the server to access the .wsgi.
I'm really not an apache guru though so don't take this example as perfect. *(I think all that is needed is the `order Allow, deny` and `allow from all`)*

a good site to check out: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango